# To do application using python's tkinter and sqlite3

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

I program python as a hobby and wanted to learn how to apply databases in a functional program, while at the same time make something useful. so I made a to do application with some basic functionalities.

- add new to do task
- look at all tasks
- delete a task

This is the first time I used sqlite3, and I'm not very experienced with tkinter either. Which is why I'm certain that this program still has a lot of room for improvement. Can anyone tell me how to improve my code? Please keep in mind that I only program as a hobby and never even touched a book on how to program so I'm uncertain if the program is built properly. In addition I struggled with the DB queries a lot, so maybe some pointers how to improve those too?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import sqlite3
import time

#shouldn't use global...
#could not find a more efficient way to access my database in the whole program

global cur, con
con = sqlite3.connect(r"C:/Users/PycharmProjects/Programs/to_do_list.db")
cur = con.cursor()


class to_do_menu(Toplevel):

    '''
    this is a script for a to do application.
    It makes use of the Database editor sqlite3 for the queries and tkinkter for the 'application' look
    the basic functionalities are adding a to do task, viewing all your tasks and deleting one
    '''

    def __init__(self, fwindow):

        #make the base application here with 4 buttons


        self.fwindow = fwindow

        self.fwindow.title('to do application')

        self.fwindow.geometry('300x150')

        self.option1 = Button(self.fwindow, text='press here to write a new task', command=write_tasks).pack(expand=True)
        self.option2 = Button(self.fwindow, text='press here to view your tasks', command=view_tasks).pack(expand=True)
        self.option3 = Button(self.fwindow, text='press here to clear a task', command=remove_task).pack(expand=True)
        self.option4 = Button(self.fwindow, text='press here to quit app', command=leave).pack(expand=True)

        self.make_db()
        self.fwindow.mainloop()

    def make_db(self):

        #make a database, if the database already exists the function will be ignored

        try:
            cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE ToDoList(tasks)''')
            con.commit()

        except Exception:
            pass

class write_tasks(Tk):

    '''
    this class writes the to do tasks to the database
    '''

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.geometry('275x200')

        self.title('Write tasks here')

        self.explenation = Label(self, text='Enter a to do task below:')
        self.explenation.pack(expand=True)

        self.activity = Entry(self)
        self.activity.pack(expand=True)

        self.getatribute = Button(self, text='press here to enter task in list', command=self.write_to_db)
        self.getatribute.pack(expand=True)

        self.new_entry = Button(self, text='Press here to clear the entry', command=self.clearline)
        self.new_entry.pack(expand=True)

        self.letsgo = Button(self, text='press here to leave this function', command=self.close)
        self.letsgo.pack(expand=True)

    def write_to_db(self):

        #write the full query to the database. Bit simple, but simple is good
        #also i'm not skilled enough to make it more complicated

        the_input = self.activity.get()

        try:
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO ToDoList(tasks) VALUES (?)", [the_input])
            con.commit()

        except Exception as fuck:
            print(fuck)

    def close(self):
        #close the child window
        self.destroy()

    def clearline(self):
        #Manually clear the query
        self.activity.delete(0, 'end')

class view_tasks(Tk):

    '''
    View all tasks visible in DB
    '''

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title('current tasks')
        self.geometry('250x200')

        self.show_all_input()

    def show_all_input(self):

        #list all tasks in a new window
        #want to make this prettier, but it's fine for now

        self.item_list = self.setvar()
        self.item = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM ToDoList")
        self.rows = self.item.fetchall()

        self.go = Button(self, text='press here to leave this function', command=self.leave)

        for i in self.rows:
            self.the_items = Label(self, text=i)
            self.the_items.pack(expand=True)

    def leave(self):
        self.destroy()

class remove_task(Tk):

    '''
    Remove a function out of the DB
    '''

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()

        self.title('Task remover')
        self.geometry('250x125')

        self.coaching = Label(self, text='enter the task you wish to remove').pack(expand=True)

        self.remove = Entry(self)
        self.remove.pack(expand=True)

        self.butt = Button(self, text='search for task', command=self.checkindb).pack(expand=True)
        self.left = Button(self, text='leave this function', command=self.close).pack(expand=True)

    def checkindb(self):

        the_item = self.remove.get()

        #if the task is exactly the same as the query the task will imidiatly be cleared
        #for some reason only seems to work with singular letters/numbers.
        #Why I don't know but I'm not good enough with databases to figure it out, so we're taking it.

        try:
            cur.execute("DELETE FROM ToDoList WHERE tasks=(?)", the_item)
            con.commit()

        except Exception:
            #if the task is more than one letter the guess function will be applied to find something similar to the query
            guess = self.almost_right(the_item)

            #if the guess can't find anything an error message will pop up
            if not guess:
                messagebox.showerror(title='ERROR', message='ITEM NOT FOUND')
            #if the guess can find something the child window will be destroyed upon completion
            elif guess:
                self.destroy()

    def almost_right(self, item):

        #if the to do task is not properly written the app will try to find similarities with what was asked and whats in the db.
        #I strugled with this part, which is why the code is somewhat spaghetti.

        try:
            guess = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM ToDoList WHERE tasks LIKE (?)", ([item])).fetchone()[0]

            maybe = str(guess).strip()

            #if the query returns none the function will return false.
            #not even sure I needed the maybe var, but it works now so i'm not touching anything
            #wasn't sure if maybe was a str saying none or just nonetype so i raised both in my if
            if maybe != 'None' or maybe != None:

                #the query has to be verified by the user to avoid deleting the worng item.
                my_guess = messagebox.askquestion(title='the following query was found:', message=(guess, '\n delete this item?'))

                if my_guess == 'yes':

                    cur.execute("DELETE FROM ToDoList WHERE tasks LIKE (?)", ([guess,])).fetchone()
                    con.commit()

                    messagebox.showinfo(title='WELL DONE', message='Task completed. good job!')
                    return True
                else:
                    return False
            else:
                return False
        except Exception:
            return False

    def close(self):
        self.destroy()

class leave:

    '''
    this function is to fully close the application
    '''

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        quit()

window = Tk()
to_do_menu(window)
```

The 'app' itself doesn't look great, but this question is more for improvement of the functionality and construction of the program, as I want it to work good before I start with the front-end.
Lastly, I'd also like to add more functions to the code but I don't know what, so if you can think of any (simple) functions that could be added please let me know!
Thanks in advance!!